# Oracle changing 'N' to 'u'

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a procedure in which one of the lines looks like this:

```
WHERE zzrectyp = 'N'
```

However, everytime I compile the procedure, the line automatically changes to

```
WHERE zzrectyp = 'u'
```

Ultimately, I've changed the line to this in order to avoid Oracle changing it, but I would like to know where is this change coming from as I can't find anything related in the docs.

```
WHERE zzrectyp = CHR(78)
```

UPDATE: as per Alex Poole's answer, it seems there's a bug in the current version of my IDE (SQL Developer) which was fixed in later versions.

Comment: Pleas, provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and describe what IDE you use. Literals should not be replaced by the DBMS, so it couldn't be documented.

Comment: What do you get from the output of `SELECT DUMP('N') FROM DUAL` where you copy-paste the `'N'` from **YOUR** code. Are there multiple characters or only a single character?

Comment: @MT0 This what's appearing for me Typ=96 Len=1: 78

Comment: @astentx I'm using SQL Developer. I cannot replicate it in another procedure even if I copypaste the same line of code :(

Comment: That's only a single character with the character code `78` (i.e. a single `N`). It should not be replaced so you would need to look for some setting on the IDE that is doing the replacement.

Comment: @MT0 thanks for your answer. Where in my IDE could I check for this?

Comment: No idea as, as far as I know, this should not happen. If all else fails, log into SQL/Plus (or any other IDE) and compile the procedure there and see if it changes; if it does then its a database issue and not an IDE issue.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the same procedure you compiled?

Comment: SQL Developer will change `N'some text'` to `u'some text'`, which is expected (see MoS doc ID 2533716.1). Clearly that isn't what you describe happening, but the N/u involved makes me wonder if the specific version you are using is somehow confused by that. Which version of SQL Developer are you seeing this in? And how are you supply the initial code, compiling, and checking the final code - all from the object browser?

Comment: It seems [you are not alone](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4036642/very-strange-mutilation). I suspect you're on an old version with a bug, and upgrading to the current version will resolve it.

Comment: [This is also similar](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/comment/14788193) but is apparently a JDBC bug, and still happens in 20.4 with Java 1.8.0_271.

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole for confirmation. I've just replaced 'N' by CHR(78) since I cannot upgrade the IDE version for the time being.

Comment: @banana_99 other workaround is to replace it with `upper('n')` but that is a matter of preference.

Comment: @MartinSchapendonk - if it is related to confusion of the nchar/unicode literal conversion then I'd expect lowercase `'n'` to have the same issue; it certainly does for the JDBC version.

Comment: @Alex Poole indeed I assumed it only happened on 'N', if 'n' is also affected then ignore my comment :-)